# Hibernate. Join одного из полей сущности

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Начинаю изучать hibernate, возник вопрос.

Довольно синтетический пример: есть две таблицы:

transactions:
`id | transactionCategoryId | amount`

transaction_categories: `id | name`

Хотелось бы с использованием hibernate сделать что-то подобное:

```
select t.*, tc.name as categoryName 
  from transactions as t 
  inner join transaction_categories tc 
on t.categoryId = tc.id;
```

Понятно, что есть `@OneToOne`, но если мне не надо джоинить сразу все поля, а надо всего лишь одно? Я пробовал использовать `@Formula`, но, во-первых, она делает подзапрос (что логично), а не `join`, а во-вторых, поля, обозначенные формулой почему-то не вычисляются при возвращении объекта из `saveAndFlush`.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не понял... джойнятся - таблицы, а не поля. а если не надо ПОЛУЧАть все поля - так и не надо ляпать в список полей вывода звёздочки, надо перечислять только то, что требуется. Остальное, вероятно, относится к начинке hibernate, ибо с точки зрения SQL выглядит полным бредом.

Comment: Join таблицы для присоединения одного поля выглядит для вас бредом? Звездочка стоит после первой таблицы. Значит мне нужны все поля первой таблицы. Из второй таблицы мне нужно только одно поле.

Comment: непонятен суть вопроса или проблемы

Comment: @VladimirovAlexey Некорректными выглядят `@OneToOne`, `@Formula` и т.п. - ибо в терминах MySQL это локальные переменные. Опять же - соединяются таблицы, т.е. все целиком, и только потом из них выгребаются нужные поля, неважно, одно, два или все.

Comment: @Akina согласен, соединяются таблицы, криво сказал. Но вопрос как раз в том, можно ли используя Hibernate в одной сущности описать поле, которое будет физически находиться в другой таблице. С помощью `@Formula` это можно сделать, но выгладит в итоге это довольно костыльно (тк, очевидно, эта аннотация немного не для того сделана, и вообще, делать это подзапросом не комильфо). `@OneToOne` можно примапить другую таблицу, но при ответе в JSON сами понимаете что получится (подобъект). А хочется - Отдельное поле. Пусть это будет `String name`.

Comment: @VladimirovAlexey почему через хибернейт не хотите получить одну сущность `transactions`, а потом вызывать `transaction.getTrCategory();`  зачем вам все в одном поле ?  вы также можете использовать FK или RK и сджоинить не придется, так как каждый экземпляр будет иметь значение другого ключа при выборке

Comment: @SeniorAutomator так и сделал в итоге как раз через `.getTrCategory()`, просто надеялся, что есть более изящный путь. Повторюсь, совсем новичок в hibernate.

Comment: @VladimirovAlexey [на фото](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Capture.1486937162.png) можно увидеть, что у меня есть поле `customer_id`, которое при выборке видно и она ссылается на значение  другой таблицы. `FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (id)`. я думаю это то, что вы хотите

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16065433/2908793